# Move existing element into a new TR underneath another TR using JQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I want to achieve move a panel with different elements inside just right next to the row clicked in the command button on a html table, something like this:

```
jQuery("[id*=lnkButton]").click(function () { 
   $(this).closest('tr').after("<tr class ='alt'><td> appendTo here </td></tr>");
   //$("#source").appendTo("#destination"); how to run this line inside TD and make the panel visible in there upon inserted 
}
```

This is the panel I want to move to the new created row:

```
<asp:Panel ID='panelPhotos' runat='server' Visible="False"> a lot of elements</Panel>
```

The panel contain server controls like buttons with click event linked...

This is the table (GridView):

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridScopeItem" runat="server" AllowPaging="True"  DataKeyNames="ItemID" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnPageIndexChanging="gridScopeItem_PageIndexChanging" OnRowCommand="gridScopeItem_RowCommand" OnSelectedIndexChanged="gridScopeItem_SelectedIndexChanged"
    PageSize="10" Caption="Scope Items" ClientIDMode="Static">
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="ItemID" HeaderText="Item ID"/>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Cat" HeaderText="CAT" ReadOnly="true"/>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Sel" HeaderText="SEL" ReadOnly="true"/>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Activity" HeaderText="ACT" ReadOnly="true"/>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="SpecDetailedDescription" ReadOnly="true" HeaderText="Description" />
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="Link1" CommandName="detail" CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>" Text="<img src='img/upload.png' title= 'Upload Pictures' style='max-height: 20px; max-width: 30px;' />" />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>                           
</Columns>
```

So when I click on that LinkButton I need to add the new TR/TD and inside that existing panel(panelPhotos).

Comment: You might want to post some HTML and not the ASP.NET.

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/q8vof2fa/

```
$("body").on("click", "td", function() {
    $(this).closest("tr").after("<tr><td> appendTo here </td><tr>");
});
```

Something like this? Click on a `<td>` element and it appends a `<tr>` element after its parent.

Comment: No, actually I'm able to add the new tr and td, what I need is to add the existing panel inside that td just created (this action should be performed on the event click of the LinkButton).